# JVM - How much RAM should I allocate

Tags: java, jvm, ram, jvm-arguments

I didn't find a suggestion on how much RAM I actually should allocate to the JVM.

Assuming that my computer has 4GB RAM and runs Windows 10. I nearly only use Java Applications on it. With how much RAM should I start the JVM? The system needs RAM for itself too, so in my logic, I should not allocate 4 GB even if that is possible.

This isn't a black/white question, I just want to have an idea and how to come to an answer in this question.

Comment: There's no good general answer to this, it completely depends on how much RAM the Java program that you are using needs.

Comment: @Jesper: What if I run 4 programs in parallel? Can I still allocate 2GB for every of that program? Or will each application take 2GB on it's own and the computer may run out of ram?

Comment: When you start a Java program, you start a new instance of the JVM, which will allocate at most whatever amount of memory you specify (with the `-Xmx` option). 4 programs = 4 JVMs which will each allocate at most 2 GB if you'd use `-Xmx=2G`.

Comment: Unless you run into a memory related problem I would suggest you use the JVM defaults, which are sensible for many usages.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen The problem is: We have a business application here that often reaches to the maximum allocated Ram, which makes it lag a lot if a user has too many "tabs" open. Using the "default's" won't make it more deterministic. We may increase the heap size and limit the amount of open tabs.

Comment: Why does it lag?  Have you profiled it?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen We display the current memory usage and the max memory available. It always starts to lag when the GC needs to make a cleanup.

Comment: An operating system’s memory management is way more complicated than you can express with a single number. Further, did you ever calculate, how much time you are already thinking about that, what your company has to pay for that time and how many GB RAM the company could have bought instead? I guess, multiples of these 4GB…

Comment: I would suggest attaching with JVisualVM to a troublesome instance and watch it more closely than that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I didn't find a suggestion on how much RAM I actually should allocate to the JVM.

The JVM has a default setting of 1/4 of main memory. If you have 4 GB it will default to 1 GB.

Note: this is a pretty small system and you get get some embedded devices and phones which this much memory.

If you can afford to buy a little more memory it will make your life easier.

> I nearly only use Java Applications on it. With how much RAM should I start the JVM?

Unless you have a reason to change a command line parameter I would leave it as it is.

Note: you OS will need some memory, perhaps 1 GB and you want to leave 1 GB free for caching etc, so you could increase the heap size to 2 GB, but only if you needed to.

> What if I run 4 programs in parallel? Can I still allocate 2GB for every of that program?

Yes, but it's a very bad idea. You application will start swapping and your computer can become unusable. I would try to stay under 2 GB total for this machine.

> We have a business application here that often reaches to the maximum allocated Ram, which makes it lag a lot if a user has too many "tabs" open.

In that case, you should make sure you have the right tool for the job which means making sure your system has enough memory.  4 GB of memory costs $18.  If you had a hobby PC with 4 GB, I would say, get more memory.  Three years ago, my 8 year old son when he turned 8 I gave him a PC with 8 GB of memory because it's didn't make sense to buy less.  I would just get 16 GB or 32 GB minimum. Then its worth spending some time tuning it, maybe.

Answer (score 1):

you can type "jconsole" or "jmc" in command line to see how much memory java used.